# Python/Pandas : Dividing contents of one big folder into small folders based on DataFrame condition

Tags: python, pandas

I have five different DataFrames A1, A2, A3, A4, A5.
Now I want to do the same operations on all of them. 
I want to move the contents of some folder to different folders. whose names are same as dataframe names.
More precisely, I have some images in source folder that I want to divide in five different folders
Here is my piece of code

```
namelist=['A1','A2','A3','A4','A5']
for name in namelist:   
            for index, row in name.iterrows():   
                try:
                    shutil.move(’Source_folder’+ row['file_name'], ‘Destination’+name+'/'+ row['file_name']) 
                except(FileNotFoundError):
                    pass
```

But I am getting AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'iterrows'

Trial II

```
    for df in (A1, A2, A3,A4,A5):    
        for index, row in df.iterrows():   
            try:
                shutil.move(’source_folder’+ row['file_name'], ‘Destination’+df+'/'+ row['file_name']) 
            except(FileNotFoundError):
                pass
```

I get this error `TypeError: Could not compare [‘Destination’] with block values`.
When I try this code for each DataFrame separately it works but when I try to do for all DataFrames in a loop it is not working at all. Please help!

Comment: A `name` in `namelist` is a string, that's where the first error is coming from.

Comment: 'namelist' is a list of strings, not dfs, that's why it has no attribute/method called iterrows. You need to remove the quotation marks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider iterating elementwise between dataframe names and objects with `zip`. Right now you are attempting to concatenate an entire dataframe object, *df*, in the destination path string:

```
for name, df in zip(['A1','A2','A3','A4','A5'], [A1,A2,A3,A4,A5]):    
   for index, row in df.iterrows():   
       try:
           shutil.move('source_folder' +'/'+ row['file_name'], 
                       'Destination'+ name +'/'+ row['file_name']) 
       except(FileNotFoundError):
           pass
```

Alternatively, use a dictionary and iterate through its keys and values. Also, use `os.path.join()` and avoid concatenating forward/back slashes in directory names:

```
import os

df_dict = {'A1': A1, 'A2': A2, 'A3': A3, 'A4': A4, 'A5': A5}

for name, df in df_dict.items():    
   for index, row in df.iterrows():   
       try:
           shutil.move(os.path.join('source_folder', row['file_name']), 
                       os.path.join('Destination'+ name, row['file_name'])) 
       except(FileNotFoundError):
           pass
```

---

By the way, consider saving similar structured dataframe objects in a container like list or dictionary from the start and avoid the many named objects flooding your global environment. Don't do this just for the loop! You can run any dataframe operation accordingly:

```
df_dict['A1'].head(...)
df_dict['A1'].describe(...)
df_dict['A1'].groupby(...)
```

Comment: No problem. Glad to help!